# Convert a query result into a list using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a query that gives a result as given below.

```
abc=[(1531,), (4325,), (9204,)]
```

How do I convert it into a list as below?

```
def=['1531','4325','9204']
```

I will always have integer and not string as my result.

Comment: Query result from what? What have you tried/researched?

Comment: This is the query that I had so far. import cx_Oracle
querystring = '''myquery'''

con = cx_Oracle.connect('id','pwd','server')
cursor= con.cursor()
r=cursor.execute(querystring)
abc= cursor.fetchall()
print(rows)

def=''.join([str(i) for i in rows])
print(cusip)
cursor.close()
con.close()

Comment: Use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51319801/edit) button to update your question, it sounds like it'd be a better idea to improve your query to just return whatever those numbers represent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand, it's so easy with loop. Why use others complicated?

```
abc = [(1531,), (4325,), (9204,)]
def_ = []

for i in abc:
    def_.append(str(i[0]))

print(def_)
```

Comment: What if a tuple contains more than one number?

Comment: You can also use loop to get it !

Answer (score 1):

```
import itertools
abc=[(1531,), (4325,), (9204,)]
print( list(map(str, itertools.chain.from_iterable(abc))) )
```

**Output:**

```
['1531', '4325', '9204']
```

- `itertools.chain.from_iterable` to flatten the list
- `map` to convert all elements in list to str

Answer (score 0):

With iterator:

```
from operator import itemgetter
print(list(map(itemgetter(0), abc)))
```

With list comprehension:

```
print([i[0] for i in abc])
```

Both output:

```
[1531, 4325, 9204]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `itertools` -

```
import itertools
abc = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(abc))
```

Using list comprehension -

```
[i for x in abc for i in x]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use normal list comprehension

```
>>> abc = [(1531,), (4325,), (9204,)]
>>> dfg = [val for items in abc for val in items]
>>> dfg
[1531, 4325, 9204]
```

If the size of the query result is too large, consider using `itertools.chain`

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> list(chain(*abc))
[1531, 4325, 9204]
```